# Express: How can I handle this? (About `Route`)

Tags: node.js, express

I am beginner at `node.js` and `express`.

In my example project, firstly, I made an express project.
And I want to add a page named `/product`.

So, I take these steps.

1. Add `product.jade` file at `views` folder.
2. Add `product.js` file at `routes` folder.
3. revise `app.js`.

The `product.jade` is like this.

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 #{title}
    p Product Info.
```

The `product.js` is like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET product info. */
router.get('/product', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('product', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Finally, I revised `app.js`. I added two lines.

One is`var productRouter = require('./routes/product');`,

and the other is `app.use('/product', productRouter);`.

I was expecting it works.

But when I enter at `localhost:3000/product`, I only can see `404, Not Found`.

Please help. What am I missing?

--- EDIT ---

`app.js`

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var productRouter = require('./routes/product');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/product', productRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: No need of specifying `/product` in both routes.js and app.js. it will become `/product/product` . So use `*` in app.js inplace of /product

Comment: Show your `app.js`

Comment: @REDDYPRASAD Sorry, I can not understand... Can you explain it code?

Comment: `app.use('/product', productRouter); // http://example.com/product`  and next : `router.get('/product', ...) // http://example.com/product/product` so @reddy tells you to  `app.use('*', productRouter);` so that all requests will pass thought your productRouter-middleware but you can even take it one step further: `app.use(productRouter);`

Comment: @ippi @REDDYPRASAD I handle it! The problem is `product.js`. I revise `/product'` to `'/'`, and It works very well! Thanks your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a route for `/product/product` because your middleware specifies `/product` with this line:

```
app.use('/product', productRouter);
```

And, then your route again specifies `/product` in addition to that with this line:

```
router.get('/product', function(req, res, next) {...}
```

That creates a route for `/product/product`.

---

There are a couple ways to fix this.  If your intention is that the `productRouter` handles all routes that start with `/product`, then leave the `app.use()` the same and change from this:

```
router.get('/product', function(req, res, next) {...}
```

to this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {...}
```

---

If you don't intend to have multiple routes that start with `/product` and only need to define the one `/product` route handler, then you don't need to create a whole separate router just for that.  You could instead, just export the route handler from product.js (instead of exporting the router) and then just use:

```
app.get('/product', require('./routes/product'));
```

That would put just a single route handler in product.js and avoid creating a router for just one route.

Comment: @s.p. - Does this answer your question?